# Why does awk's system() call behave this way?

Tags: awk, gawk

I'm trying to perform a grep inside awk using system() which according to the manual should return the exit code of the command being run.

```
$ cat foo.txt
bar
$ grep -q bar foo.txt; echo $?
0
$ awk 'BEGIN{ if ( system( "grep -q bar foo.txt" ) ) { print "yes" } else { print "no" } }'
no
```

If I remove the `-q` I can see that grep is indeed finding `bar` so it should exit 0 and therefore print yes, no?

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ if ( system( "grep bar foo.txt" ) ) { print "yes" } else { print "no" } }'
bar
no
```

Completely removing `grep` from the equation:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ if ( system( "true" ) ) { print "yes" } else { print "no" } }'
no
```

Comment: `if (0) { ... } else { ... }`

Comment: @Kusalananda: Well that is just awkward.

Comment: Perhaps `if (system("true") == 0) { ...success... }` is less awkward

Comment: Oddly the match() function has the opposite behavior.

Comment: @Jesse_b Well yes. `match()` returns the position of the match, and zero for no match.

Comment: I don't get why you would call `grep` from `awk`. However I can see it could be useful to call other programs (e.g. json or xml prasers).

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor: I was planning to read from one file and grep for matches in another like: `awk '{ if ( ! "grep -q "$NF" bar.txt) { do something } }' foo.txt`

Comment: @Jesse_b don't call grep from awk like that, think about the stack of calls `shell { awk { system { shell { grep } } } }` and the fact you're spawning a new shell for every call to grep. What you describe is a common use case and there's better ways to do it - post a new question if you'd like help with that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In shell, the exit code 0 stands for success of a command, and any other for failure (and its reason). That's what `system` returns: 0 for success, but `awk` interprets this as FALSE. You need to invert the logics.

Comment: Well doh, thanks!

Comment: Right, it's the difference between an **exit status** (0=success, non-zero=failure) and a **condition** (0=false, non-zero=true). What `0` means depends if your using it as an exit status as in a shell test `if [ 0 ]; then` or a condition as in an awk if statement `if ( 0 ) {`